# Beanshell XOR throwing error

Tags: java, beanshell

When I try to use the xor operator:

```
if(a ^ b)
```

I get the following error:

> internal Error: unimplemented binary operator

Is there another way to do it in beanshell, or should I just do:

```
if((a && !b) || (!a && b))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(a != b)` is equivalent to XOR (`a ^ b`) for booleans.

Comment: I can't believe binary operators not implemented in beanshell in 2013. Dead language :/

Answer (score 2):

In Beanshell2 the xor operator is implemented, see http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2

Comment: this looks dead, isn't it?

Comment: It's a bit on hold - because there are some activities from Apache to adopt the original Beanshell project. But the google code project is still maintained..